# How to write Sparc assembly and run its binary in Qemu or Simics?

Tags: assembly, qemu, sparc, simics

I am trying to start writing some Sparc assembly, but I can't figure out how to assemble and run the code. I have written arc with arcTools, but that's as far as I have gone with assembly. I have downloaded both simics and qemu, but I don't know where to go from here. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Are you running native on SPARC or cross-assembling from another architecture?

Answer (score 6):

You didn't say what operating system(s) you use.
For this example, I will assume you have linux and want to write simple standalone sparc code (for educational purposes).
You will need `binutils` and `gdb` compiled for sparc and `qemu-sparc`.
Save this small sample code as `test.s`:

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov %o0, %g0
1:
    inc %o0
    cmp %o0, 100
    bl 1b
    nop
    b .
    nop
```

Use `as` to assemble and `ld` to link, as follows:

```
$ sparc-linux-as -g -o test.o test.s
$ sparc-linux-ld -g -o test test.o
```

Should produce the binary `test`:

```
$ file test
test: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, SPARC, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

Now start `qemu-sparc` set up for `gdb` remote debugging (pick a port of your choice, I used 1234):

```
$ qemu-sparc -g 1234 test
```

It will wait for `gdb` to connect. In another terminal, start `gdb` for the binary:

```
$ sparc-linux-gdb test
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.50.20111117-cvs-debian
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=sparc-linux".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /var/tmp/test...done.
(gdb)
```

Attach to the `qemu` instance:

```
(gdb) target remote :1234
Remote debugging using :1234
_start () at test.s:3
3           mov %o0, %g0
```

From here on, you can use `gdb` as usual to execute your code, examine registers and memory.