# Run Sparc v9 64-bit executable on bare metal QEMU

Tags: qemu, sparc, qemu-device

I tried this recipe : [How to run a bare metal ELF file on QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913745/how-to-run-a-bare-metal-elf-file-on-qemu#51579116) to run bare metal `AArch64` executables on `QEMU` (and it worked). I'd like to do the same for 64-bit `SPARCv9` executables (preferably starting from `C/C++`, not assembly) - I tried the examples in this link : [Run SPARC assembly in QEMU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706317/how-to-write-sparc-assembly-and-run-its-binary-in-qemu-or-simics), but that one runs in user-mode Linux, does syscall translation to the host system, etc.

Example :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  volatile int a = 11, b = 13, c = 7, d = 5; 
  return a + b - c - d;
}
```

How do I run this example as a bare metal `Sparcv9` executable AND connect `gdb` to it ?

Any of the available 64-bit boards in `qemu/hw/sparc64/` would be fine. Thank you.

Comment: In addition to my answer, I just thought I'd recommend using [renode](https://renode.io/) as an alternative to qemu. While not as high performance, it is a modern alternative, that has first-class support for emulating custom peripherals, which is often half the difficulty in bare-metal emulation.

Comment: That's a slightly weird thing to want to run as a bare metal executable, because it starts at main() and returns a value from it, which is to say it's assuming a libc runtime and is not really 'bare metal'.

Comment: In the `AArch64` example I posted, the program writes couple of characters to the board's UART. I'd like to achieve the same, but didn't want to specialize the question to a specific `SPARC` dev board.

Comment: One of the key characteristics of "bare metal" is that it is generally specific to a particular bit of hardware...

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are after is the `qemu-system-sparc64` command. Just something to note is that the general form for bare-metal emulation is `qemu-system-{ARCH}` and the general command for user mode emulation is `qemu-{ARCH}`.

An example from the [qemu docs](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/SPARC).

```
qemu-system-sparc64 \
  -drive file=hd.qcow2,if=none,id=hd \
  -device virtio-blk-pci,bus=pciB,drive=hd,bootindex=0
```

As for building your own c/c++ bare-metal executables, that's a relatively broad topic, but I'd recommend starting with GCC and newlib-nano (for libc).

Comment: From the `AArch64` link I posted - it looks like there are 2-3 very simple steps to do to run a bare metal executable on `ARM`. I am expecting an answer along the same lines ?

Comment: It seems that you are looking for a very specific type of answer. How do you feel about updating your question to specify *exactly* what you are after?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - added a very small example + exactly what I need. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's similar to running an AArch64 bare-metal ELF:

```
qemu-system-sparc64 -nographic -kernel test64.elf -serial mon:stdio -s
```

or

```
qemu-system-sparc64 -nographic -bios test64.elf -serial mon:stdio -s
```

Both -kernel and -bios options in sun4u emulation may load ELF files, the difference is that in the first example the hardware is initialized by OpenBIOS, and in the second example you are running in a PROM right after the cold start.
The -s option will make QEMU listen for an incoming connection from gdb on TCP port 1234.

In the second example you probably also would like to add the -S option in oder to make QEMU not to start the execution of your ELF file until you tell it to from gdb.
In gdb you do the following:

```
(gdb) set architecture sparc:v9
The target architecture is assumed to be sparc:v9
(gdb)  target remote localhost:1234
```